# Does asterisk has default database?

Tags: asterisk

I need to create a pbx that will be integrated to asterisk. I found a predefined asterisk installation that has vicidial in it. I wonder if I create pbx from scratch, does asterisk have already installed database that I can manipulate? or, am i the one who will normalize and develop the database for my pbx. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asterisk comes with a database that is used internally and made available for Asterisk programmers and administrators to use as they see fit.
Asterisk versions up to 1.8 used the Berkeley DB, and in version 10 the project moved to the SQLite3 database. You can read about database migration between those major versions in the section SQLite3 astdb back-end.

**Database commands on the CLI**

Sub-commands under the command "database" allow a variety of functions to be performed on or with the database.

```
*CLI> core show help database
database del                   -- Removes database key/value
database deltree               -- Removes database keytree/values
database get                   -- Gets database value
database put                   -- Adds/updates database value
database query                 -- Run a user-specified query on the astdb
database show                  -- Shows database contents
database showkey               -- Shows database contents
```

Read up on [Asterisk Internal Database](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Internal+Database)

Comment: Thanks, how about the actual crm database like in the vicidial. Since the internal database is for asterisk. I will need to create my own database for user authentication, caller logs etc?

Comment: Im on my phone but look up asterisk cdr for that

Answer (score 1):

Seams you mean mysql database.

No, by default asterisk have no mysql support. In version 11.* even have no mysql support at all(used odbc).

You can compile mysql/odbc and use external mysql via asterisk realtime or func_odbc in your dialplan.

There are some patterns for tables if you use realtime(see asterisk source). Nothing force you use any pattern if you use func_odbc.